# .NET - Upgrade settings when using NullSoft Installer

Tags: .net, settings

I just recently switched to using the NullSoft Installer for my .NET application.  By default, .NET supports the Settings.Upgrade() method to upgrade the corresponding settings.  I'm still using the standard settings file for my application but I'm not sure how to implement a way to upgrade the settings when necessary (such as a newer install) when using NullSoft Installer.

For example, this is where the settings are stored when using the NullSoft Installer:

C:\Program Files\Application\Application.exe.config

When the user installs a newer version of the application, I want to be able to keep the users defined settings, while upgrading/removing/adding new settings to that file.

Is there already an existing way to do this, or will I have to somehow implement a new method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this in my app by storing the application version in the Settings:

```
    public static void UpgradeSettingsIfRequired()
    {
        string version = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
        if (Settings.Default.CurrentVersion != version)
        {
            Settings.Default.Upgrade();
            Settings.Default.CurrentVersion = version;
            Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
```